# Hausdorff $2$-dimensional measure of $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I know that $\mathcal{H}^2(\mathbf{R}) = 0$, but what is any easy way to see it? I tried coming up with reasonable covers, but they all seem to give upper bounds that are too large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cover by rectangles of small radius. Fix $\delta>0$ and consider covering of $\mathbb{R}$ by intervals of length $\frac{\delta}{n}$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. This is possible in view of the divergence of the harmonic series. Namely, ignoring $\delta>0$ for a moment, start with $[0,1]$, then consider $[1, 1 + 1/2]$, $[1+1/2, 1+1/2+1/3]$, ... . Repeat the same construction for the negative axis. We get a countable cover of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\{I_n\}$ be some enumeration of these intervals (the exact order does not matter). For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, consider a rectangle of height $\delta>0$ whose side length is equal to the length of $I_n$ and which contains the interval $I_n$. Then the union $\bigcup\limits_{n}^\infty I_n$ covers $\mathbb{R}$ with sets of diameter bounded above by $2\delta$. However
$$
H^2_{2\delta}(\mathbb{R}) \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{diam}(I_n)^2 \leq 2\delta^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 10 \delta^2,
$$
hence $H^2(\mathbb{R}) = \lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} H^2_\delta(\mathbb{R}) = 0$.

Comment: Got it. Another way to do the argument is to first show that $H^2((-n, n))= 0$, which follows since $H^1((-n, n)) = 2n$, hence $H^\alpha((-n, n)) = 0$ for all $\alpha > 1$. Now $H^2(\mathbf{R}) = \lim_n H^2((-n,n)) = 0$, by continuity of measure and measurability of Borels. This is not as elementary though, of course.

Comment: actually what goes wrong in your argument if you use this cover for $H^1$, though? I'm confused, don't you get $H^1_\delta(\mathbf{R}) \leq \delta$?

Comment: @DrewBrady, thanks for pointing this out. Actually I noticed that also, that I'm not really using the fact that we deal with $2d$ measure. I've now revised the argument. Taking small rectangles, sum of whose lengths diverge, but converge with when in squared summation. This will ensure that we cover $\mathbb{R}$ using arbitrarily small $2d$ area.

Comment: I don't understand what was wrong previously, though. Was it not a cover of $\mathbf{R}$? In particular, let $0 < \eta < 1$, and let $B_n = B(r_n, \eta \delta 2^{-n})$. Then $\mathrm{diam}(B_n) = \eta \delta 2^{1-n} < \delta$. Hence $H^1_\delta(\mathbf{R}) \leq \sum_{n} \eta \delta 2^{-n} \leq \eta \delta$. Taking $\eta \downarrow 0$, this gives $H^1_\delta(\mathbf{R}) = 0$, for all $\delta$. But this clearly can't be correct.

Comment: @DrewBrady in the argument with balls of radius $\delta 2^{-n}$ we are simple not covering $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, consider intersections of these balls with $\mathbb{R}$. For the $n$-th ball, the intersection is an interval of length $\delta 2^{-n}$. Now taking the sum over all these intervals (which do have overlaps) converges, and hence cannot cover $\mathbb{R}$ whose length is infinite.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks!